# Has a specific time for Breakaway ever been given?

Tags: space-1999

Everybody who has ever seen "Space: 1999" knows for a fact that the exact day Breakaway happened was September 13th, 1999. What I was asking was if any part of the S:1999 media ever said on what specific hour did this event happened.

Comment: In Breakaway, Cmdr Koenig is returning to the Moon from a trip to Earth.  If you know where that administrative center was, you could estimate the hour based upon the time of day he left the facility.

Comment: @user28220: This is an awfully specific piece of minutia to ask about. What prompted you to ask?

Comment: Working on a fan fiction. Involves a bunch of lunatics trying to replicate Breakaway. Just wanted to see if there ever was an official media statement of the time to add further verisimilitude (or preventing finding out the hard way that there *is* such intel from someone nit-picking the story).

Comment: +1 for writing a fan-fiction. Now I'm going to have to re-watch *Breakaway* just to see if there are any clocks hanging out ;-)

Comment: When you do, you'll see that not only are there clocks on every comms post, but they are on screen just before the explosion and just afterwards.  They even show different times before and after.  And you'll also know the exact local time of Commander Koenig's arrival on the base, because it's given in dialogue.  It's not the time of the explosion, though, which is what the questioner asks for.